# grep. Вырезать подстроку без астериска (*)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, grep

Как с помощью grep отрезать подстроку `feature` из строки `* feature/test`

Следующая регулярка

```
echo "$(echo "* feature/test" | grep -oP '^\*\s([a-zA-Z]*)')"
```

дает

```
* feature
```

Comment: А я бы sed использовал.

Comment: Я не против решения на sed, но на сколько знаю, он использует BRE POSIX и не поддерживает расширенное написание регулярок, поэтому в своих скриптах применяю grep/awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать следующее регулярное выражение PCRE ([см. демо](https://regex101.com/r/4NEIaB/1)):

```
^\*\s*\K[a-zA-Z]+
```

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `\*` - знак `*`
- `\s*` - 0+ пробельных символов
- `\K` - оператор, очищающий буфер текущего совпадения
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1  и более букв

[См. онлайн-демо](https://ideone.com/V00ntS)

```
s='* feature/test'
echo $(grep -oP '^\*\s*\K[a-zA-Z]+' <<< "$s")
# => feature
```

Альтернативным вариантом будет решение с использованием `sed`:

```
sed 's/[^a-zA-Z]*\([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*\).*/\1/' <<< $s
# => feature
```

Тут `[^a-zA-Z]*` найдет 0+ символов, отличных от букв, `\([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*\)` захватит 1+ букв в группу №1, а `.*` найдет оставшуюся часть строки. `\1` в шаблоне замены вставит в результат только то, что было захвачено группой №1.

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает! Объясните, пожалуйста, почему такой различный результат с использованием оператора \K и без него

Comment: @while1pass *`\K` - оператор, очищающий буфер текущего совпадения*, т.е. весь текст, который был заполнен найденным текстом, удаляется. `*` и пробел(ы), найденные `^\*\s*`, удаляются посредством `\K`, в итоге остается то, что найдёт `[a-zA-Z]+`.

Comment: ок, понял. а я пытался группировкой () взять нужное совпадение