# Регулярные выражения JS. Помогите составить правильный шаблон

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Товарищи, помогите, пожалуйста составить правильный шаблон регулярного выражения.
Есть вот такой кусок текста:

```
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
<h1>System crashed</h1>
<h2>Please try to visit us later - we're working on the problem</h2>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggleDetails(); return false;">Show details</a>
<div id="detailsContainer" style="display: none;">
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 3 in the jsp file: /templates/webvideo-base/english/test-error-page.jsp
TestError cannot be resolved to a type
1: ﻿<%
2: //Please don't remove this page!
3: TestError e = new TestError();
4: %>


An error occurred at line: 3 in the jsp file: /templates/webvideo-base/english/test-error-page.jsp
TestError cannot be resolved to a type
1: ﻿<%
2: //Please don't remove this page!
3: TestError e = new TestError();
4: %>


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:589)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at com.stc.web.Page.includeTemplate(Page.java:640)
    at org.softservice.web.PlainPage.executeUnsafe(PlainPage.java:40)
    at org.softservice.web.ErrorHandlerPage.executeImpl(ErrorHandlerPage.java:28)
    at com.stc.web.Page.execute(Page.java:852)
    at com.stc.web.VirtualDirectory.executeImpl(VirtualDirectory.java:105)
    at com.stc.web.Page.execute(Page.java:852)
    at com.stc.web.PageWrapper.service(PageWrapper.java:46)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:465)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:555)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Необходимо выдернуть содержимое "detailsContainer".
Вот что у меня получилось:

```
/\<div id=\"detailsContainer\".+\>(.*)\<\/div\>/g
```

По такому шаблону ничего не найдено. Подскажите, где я не прав.
Спасибо.

Comment: См. также [Как распарсить HTML в JavaScript (англ.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-an-html-string-with-js).

Comment: @And, а как подправить выражение так чтобы при выводе не было ни строчки с 'detailsContainer', ни с '</div>'  ? Спасибо.

Comment: @And, к сожалению, последний вариант не прошел, в итоге вывелся вообще весь исходный текст.

Comment: А так: `<div.+id=.+detailsContainer.+>([\s\S]*?[^(<div)])<\/div>` ?

Comment: Идеально :) Большое, Вам, спасибо!)

Comment: Мне оформить ответ, в качестве решения? Ибо ответ который сейчас, никак не решает задачу. И не работает на данном участке html кода.

Comment: Да, я думаю так будет правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обязательно это делать с помощью регулярных выражений?

```
let div = document.getElementById('detailsContainer');
let res = div.innerHTML;
```

Такой способ не подходит?

В случае, если нужно именно регулярное выражение, то у меня сработал следующий вариант:

```
let str = '<div id="detailsContainer" style="display: none;">test</div>';
let reg = /<div id="detailsContainer" (.*)>(.*)<\/div>/;
console.log(str.match(reg)[2]);
```

В консоль выводится слово "test"

Comment: Нет, в данном случае это не код страницы, а просто текст.

Comment: @ЗахарКолуженков  А что вам мешает этот текст преобразовать в объект DOM? `var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
el.innerHTML = my_HTML_String;`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, не всегда это разумно закидывать в `DOM`, так как иногда верстка может прилететь кривоватой, а `DOM` ох как этого не любит и вы выхватите столько жопа-болей, что сами скажете, да ну его - этот `DOM`, проще регуляркой выужу, что нужно.

Comment: @And Я понимаю, однако это для нас с вами проще. А человек несведущий в регулярках может серьезно в них запутаться. Тут подводных камней будет на порядок больше (как найти этот элемент, если порядок атрибутов изменится? Что если в нем вложенные одноименные элементы?).

Comment: @ WiktorStribiżew, ну валидатор регулярных выражений, никто не отменял, тот-же [regex101](https://regex101.com/) - тестировать, все равно приходится. тем-более, уже кучи шаблонов придуманы. И все возможные генераторы.

Comment: @And Вы должны понимать, что там, где нужна рекурсия, регурлярки JavaScript не сработают. Кстати, зачем [минусовать рандомные хорошие ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/788045/182013)?

Comment: Хм, ваш ответ кому-то тоже не понравился.